# Sonarlint additional language download failing

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, sonarqube, sonarlint-vs

**Steps did:**

1. Installed Sonarlint for visual studio 2015 from market place
2. During istallation asked to install additional support for javascript. I accepted. But download failed.
3. I tried to add javascript support after install from Options > Sonar lint for visual studio > Activate.

**Issue**:

Download not starting for ever. Then i got a message " ***Failed to activate support for additional languages. The remote name could not be resolved: repo1.maven.org.***"

Comment: If you open in your browser: http://repo1.maven.org/
Do you see the following page?:
Index of /
maven2/                                            2016-01-19 14:00

Comment: Yes. I see the index page. But the issue got resolved. I uninstalled and installed it again. Then it throwing another error about proxy authentication. I tried to add the default proxy settings in devenv.exe.config file of visual studio and it fixed the issue. Additional language support got activated. Thank you for looking into this.